# How to modify allow_url_fopen Local Value

Tags: security, php, .htaccess, configuration, php.ini

This is a question about PHP configuration on a LAMP server.

I want to turn off `allow_url_fopen` on one virtual host but not the other (i.e. can't turn it off globally in php.ini). The other day I had the same requirement but with `register_globals` and it was easy, I just added the following to the *.htaccess* file in the `DOCUMENT_ROOT` of the virtual host:

```
php_flag register_globals 0
```

But the same doesn't seem to work for `allow_url_fopen`. If I add

```
php_flag allow_url_fopen 0
```

to my *.htaccess* nothing happens *phpinfo()* shows `local value On`, `global value On`.

What am I doing wrong?

PS: I restarted Apache after modifying the *.htaccess* file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are flags that are PHP_INI_SYSTEM. That means you can change their value only in php.ini.

Hope that helps you.

McX

Comment: Thank you - You're right. Looking at http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php I can see the allow_url_fopen option is marked as "PHP_INI_SYSTEM" for my version of PHP which means I can't change it in a .htaccess file, only the php.ini.